# Career Messages; "no phone number given" even though phone number is in my profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Even though I have a phone number in my careers.stackoverflow profile:

[image: My Profile Page]

That phone number isn't appearing in the replies I compose to potential employers:

[image: No Phone Number Given]

Is this an option that can be turned on or is this simply a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually by design.  When you apply to a job or an employer finds you in search, a small snapshot is taken of your contact details and it can not be changed from that point forward.  Can you imagine how much more difficult an employers job would be if every resume they received had dynamic names, phone numbers, email addresses and city/state locations (which you can't see here but is also provided to employers)?

If you'd like to update the phone number for an employer after the contact details are set, the recommended way is to just send them another message with your phone number attached.

Comment: Soooo if this is "by design", perhaps the "no phone number given" labels (which apparently never change) should be *removed* then??

Comment: Or, if I reply to the prospective employer that I am indeed interested in the job (it's a checkbox or radio button between "interested" and "not interested", IIRC), the phone number I entered into my profile in should be copied into that label so the employer can reach out to me in voice and in real time. I could certainly verify my phone number before I click "send" on the message.

Comment: If your phone number had been set when this employer saved you from search, the phone number would have been copied over.  Since that wasn't the case, yes it is frozen in time.  I will bring up you suggestion about removing the "missing" messages in our next status meeting on Monday.

Comment: Thanks for responding @Nick ; AFAIK, my phone number has always been a part of my Careers profile (since I want potential employers to be able to reach out to me), so I'm thinking this functionality is not behaving as you're expecting.

Comment: I apologize for the trouble here, I should have double checked the code was correct.  It was in fact not saving the phone number when you were saved from search.  This was a bug and the fix will be live sometime in the next 30 minutes.  I will also backfill the missing phone numbers, so you'll know when this fix is live.